# Book gives different answer

Tags: calculus

I was helping someone with some Calculus 1 problems (True/False) and one of the problems was: If the line $x=1$ is a vertical asymptote of $y=f(x)$ then $f$ is not defined at $1$. I said it is true by Vertical Line Test. A function can not intersect its vertical asymptote. But the answer key says False and we were looking for a counter example. Any suggestions?

EDIT: With piece wise functions as shown in the answer I can see it work. I am relaying this to the student. Thanks for the very quick replies!

Comment: Just take any function with an asymptote and define the function at that point to be whatever you want (e.g. as a "piecewise function")

Comment: What definition of "vertical asymptote" are you using? I have seen several.

Comment: I think the biggest problem here is the vague assumption that functions are somehow defined independently of defining agents, iow humans. A function is defined if we do so define it, and otherwise isn't if we don't want it. Thus, if the line $x=1$ is a vertical asymptote to the curve $y=f(x),$ this tells us nothing about the infinitely many functions we may define by this equation -- first, by specifying domains, and defining the function using other means to suit our needs, etc.

Comment: @RoryDaulton I literally copied the question so that is the only information available. But with the introduction of piece wise functions, I can see from the answers that options are available. Remember though, it is from a Calculus 1 course.

Comment: Ok, point well taken all. If piece wise functions are allowed, then there are plenty of options. Didn't think of that and not sure if a novice Calculus 1 student would come up with that. I am going to relay this to him. Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(x)=\left\{
\begin{align*}
\frac1{x-1} & \textrm{ if } x\neq1\\
1 &\textrm{ if } x=1
\end{align*}
\right.$$
is not the most elegant of solutions, but serves as a counter example.

Comment: Elegant or not doesn't matter, a counter example is a counter example! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take $f(x)=1/x$ for $x>0$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x\leqslant 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Make $f(x)$ a piecewise defined function so that $f(x)$ is defined at the vertical asymptote of $x=1$. Andrew's answer defines one such piecewise defined function. Another function is

$$f(x)=\left\{
\begin{align*}
-\frac{1}{(x-1)^2} & \textrm{ if } x\neq1\\
-1 &\textrm{ if } x=1
\end{align*}
\right.$$

I think that you can construct an infinite amount of these piecewise defined functions that would all serve as counter examples.